# Unable to resolve react-dom

Tags: react-native, react-dom

```
Loading dependency graph, done.
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░ 99.1% (447/450)::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [02/Nov/2019:05:14:18 +0000] "GET /index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-dom` from `node_modules\react-background-slideshow\dist\index.js`: react-dom could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\u60463\BackgroundState\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:186:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\Users\u60463\BackgroundState\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\u60463\BackgroundState\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:282:16)
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\u60463\BackgroundState\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:267:42)
    at dependencies.map.result (C:\Users\u60463\BackgroundState\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:426:31)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\u60463\BackgroundState\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:423:18)
    at C:\Users\u60463\BackgroundState\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:275:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\u60463\BackgroundState\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░ 99.1% (447/450), failed.

error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-dom` from `node_modules\react-background-slideshow\dist\index.js`: react-dom could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\u60463\BackgroundState\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:186:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\Users\u60463\BackgroundState\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\u60463\BackgroundState\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:282:16)
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\u60463\BackgroundState\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:267:42)
    at dependencies.map.result (C:\Users\u60463\BackgroundState\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:426:31)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\u60463\BackgroundState\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:423:18)
    at C:\Users\u60463\BackgroundState\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:275:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\u60463\BackgroundState\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░ 59.0% (338/440)::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [02/Nov/2019:05:33:26 +0000] "GET /index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
 BUNDLE  [android, dev] ./index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓░░░░░░░ 59.0% (338/440), failed.

events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\u60463\BackgroundState\node_modules\.fsevents.DELETE\node_modules'
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at NodeWatcher.<anonymous> (C:\Users\u60463\BackgroundState\node_modules\sane\src\node_watcher.js:291:16)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
```

Comment: It is appreciated if you do some effort to format code and stack traces

Comment: Please add your `package.json` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The node module you are using, `react-background-slideshow`, is specifically created to be used for a React web project. You will not be able to use this package with React Native.